# Maven :Using specific dependencies in Build

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-plugin

I need to reduce Maven build to use specific jar dependencies then everything that is there in the Maven `classpath.` The dependency tree in my project is complex with huge amount dependencies coming in from parent project and are part of `classpath`. 
I have some specific jars that are required for execution of below shared maven target.
Is it possible to ensure that only these specific jars form the classpath.
The reason I need to do this is because there are some jars in the `classpath` that are making target to fail and I need to deploy a work around with minimal dependencies in classpath to make it work for the moment.

Please share what I best way to achieve.
I am totally new to Maven

Did some research on google but unable to come to any conclusion.

```
<execution>
            <id>jaxwsgenInterface</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
             <executable>java</executable>
             <longClasspath>false</longClasspath>
             <arguments>
                <arguments>-classpath</arguments>
                <classpath/>
                <argument>-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory</argument>
                <argument>-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory</argument>
                <argument>-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXTransformerFactory</argument>
                <argument>-Djavax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom=oracle.xml.xpath.JXPathFactory</argument>
                <argument>oracle.j2ee.ws.tools.wsa.Main</argument>
                <argument>jaxwsgenInterface</argument>
                <argument>wsdl</argument>
                <argument>schema/Service.wsdl</argument>
                <argument>wsdlLocation</argument>
                <argument>WEB-INF/wsdl/Service.wsdl</argument>
                <argument>output</argument>
                <argument>target/gensrc</argument>
                <argument>debug</argument>
                <argument>true</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
```

Comment: Are you trying to compile with a given classpath or to run the program with a given classpath?

Comment: I am trying to run.

Comment: Why are you trying to run the program from the Maven build? What is the purpose?

Comment: The section of code is generating source code from WSDL. There are some jar files in classpath coming from parent project which is causing some dependency issue/conflict and the build is failing.. If I run the target with specifc sets of jar files then it works fine. So I am trying to find a way for this particular project so that it ignores classpath coming from parent..and only use dependencies defined in this sub project.

Comment: 1. There are maven plugins for source code generation from WSDL. 2. It would probably be better to solve the dependency issues by defining proper versions and exclusions.